# C# windows form export to excel working fine on my system but not exporting to any other system

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I created a windows form application to read from csv to gridview, then exporting from gridview to excel. It is working fine on my system, but I sent the exe file to another system and the exe is running but not exporting the data. The error is `bad indexing`

```
 // creating Excel Application  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            // creating new WorkBook within Excel application  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            // creating new Excelsheet in workbook  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

            // store its reference to worksheet  
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

            // storing header part in Excel  
            for (int i = 1; i < PandMGDV.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i] = PandMGDV.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                worksheet.Cells[1, i].Font.Bold = true;
            }
            // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet  
            for (int gi = 0; gi < PandMGDV.Rows.Count-1; gi++)
            {
                for (int gj = 0; gj < PandMGDV.Columns.Count; gj++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[gi + 2, gj + 1] = PandMGDV.Rows[gi].Cells[gj].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            string fileName = Interaction.InputBox("Enter the name of the Excel file", "Save Excel File", "Default Text", -1, -1);
            //MessageBox.Show(fileName);

            workbook.SaveAs(fileName + ".xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            workbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            app.Quit();

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created", "File Path is 'c:\\User\\UserName\\MyDocuments\\"+ fileName + ".xls.xls'", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the application", "Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've never seen the Excel error *bad indexing*. Most Excel or C# error messages have both a numeric code and a full sentence or two of error text. Are you absolutely certain that *bad indexing* is the entire error message you're seeing?

Comment: Ungültiger Index. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)) this is the error

Comment: How do you know the path where you're saving the excel file? The only mention is in the MessageBox but is never stored in a `string` or used at all in the `SaveAs` function. Also, you can get the `MyDocuments` path of the logged user with `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`.

Comment: Also, `workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];` will return the sheet named "Sheet1" and that can cause some errors. That is probably the cause of the `bad indexing` error. Try with `workbook.Sheets[0];`